# Как реализовать переход по ссылке /ua/ на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, link

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.lang-menu').toggleClass('open');
    $($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function() {
      $('.lang-menu').removeClass('open');
      document.location.href = $(this).next().attr('href');
      $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown lang">
  <a class="langswitch" href="/">РУС<span class="down-caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="lang-menu">
    <li><a href="/ua/">УКР</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Какую задачу пытаетесь решить? И зачем вам здесь jQuery?

Comment: На сайте в верхнем углу хедера есть выбор языка - как вы видите в html коде. При наводе мышкой на РУС выпадает меню УКР ( выбор языка)
Необходимо что бы при клике,  отрабатывалась ссылка <a href="/ua/">УКР</a> и перенаправляля на оную страницу. При клике ничего не происходит. УКР просто закрывается т.е.
     $(document).click(function() {

      $('.lang-menu').removeClass('open');
      $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');

Comment: Как минимум не при наведении, а при клике. Ну выпадает меню, ну кликайте. Зачем jQuery?

Comment: При клике jQuery скрывает УКР , но и еще должен перенаправлять на страницу по ссылке на УКР версию. А он этого не делает

Answer (score 2):

У вас ссылка лежит внутри контейнера, который обрабатывает событие `onclick`. Вы, вызовом `e.preventDefault();` отключаете стандартную обработку события и, тем самым, мешаете распространить событие вглубь контейнера.

Уберите эту строку и все заработает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.lang-menu').toggleClass('open');
    $($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
//    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown lang">
  <a class="langswitch" href="/">РУС<span class="down-caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="lang-menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('Go!')">УКР</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$('.dropdown').click(function(e){

    $(this).find('.lang-menu').toggleClass('open');

    $($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));

    //e.preventDefault();

    e.stopPropagation();

    $(document).click(function(){
      
        $('.lang-menu').removeClass('open');

        $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');

    });

});
не работает всё равно